# python csv headers

Tags: python, csv

I have a set of csv headers that I am trying to match with uploads. It's not really working. Not all headers are required -- I just have to match what's in the file.

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(PathFile))
headers = reader.fieldnames
for header in sorted(set(headers)):
     if (header == 'ip') or (header == 'IP'):
         print  "IP found in Header"
```

In this case, IP is not found.

```
for row in reader:
     if row.get('IP'):
         print  "IP found in Row"
```

It's not found again. I did search on this site -- there was:

```
IP = row.get('IP', None)
```

That did not work either.

This is the file I'm using for testing:

```
Email, IP, Name, City, State, zip, country, garbage
ghfddgf@gfgs.com, 34.4.34.34,Mr GH, chicago, il ,60601, us,erw ewr 
5t4g@fdsf.com, 34.45.23.34, Mr 5t,NY,NY,10101, us, er
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on your edit, you need to [skip the initial space](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) after the comma.

This should do it:

```
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(open(PathFile),skipinitialspace=True)
```

Answer (score 9):

I am not exactly sure what you want to achieve but if you simply want to know if some columns is in CSV, and you are sure that all rows have same columns, and you want to use dict reader use this

```
s="""col1,col2,col3
ok,ok,ok
hmm,hmm,hmm
cool,cool,cool"""

import csv

reader = csv.DictReader(s.split("\n"))
print reader.fieldnames
for row in reader:
    for colName in ['col3', 'col4']:
        print "found %s %s"%(colName, colName in row)
    break
```

It outputs

```
found col3 True
found col4 False
```

or something like this will work too

```
reader = csv.reader(s.split("\n"))
columns = reader.next()
for colName in ['col3', 'col4']:
    print "found %s %s"%(colName, colName in columns)
```

Comment: that did not work either. I edited my post with file data i am trying to process. Trying to see if the header has IP in it.

Comment: as Adam Bernier, said problem was with spaces